# c++11: initialize map with explicit initializer_list object

Tags: c++11, initializer-list

In C++11 I can initalize a map with an initializer_list like this:

```
map<string, int> mymap = {{"first", 1}, {"second", 2}};
```

But not like this:

```
initializer_list<pair<string,int>> il = {{"first", 1}, {"second", 2}};

map<string, int> mymap2{il};
```

Any idea why is that? Is there a different syntax for that or is it not possible at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `initializer_list` constructor of `map` takes a list of `value_type`, which is a `pair` with first element `const`.

This will work:

```
initializer_list<pair<string const,int>> il = {{"first", 1}, {"second", 2}};
                            ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Even without `const` It should work.

Comment: @kvivek why do you say that?

Comment: I know `const` is the right way to do that, but that should not be mandatory. even without that also my code compiles.

Comment: @kvivek perhaps your compiler is noncompliant or offering an extension?

Comment: If this `map<string, int> mymap2{il};` assignment is done then, It is must to have the `const` otherwise, creating a map using `initializer_list<pair<string,int>> il = {{"first", 1}, {"second", 2}};` itself will not throw any error.

Comment: @kvivek right. What's your point?

Comment: very helpfull, i was searching a lot!, initializer list templated argument firm is not clear. i cannot find what was the error for a hours. Thx a lot